# Using jQuery .ajax for a voting script. How do I update MySQL DB after successful vote?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm assuming I have to put something in the success option. However what I have isn't working.

I declare this JS function on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function performAjaxSubmission() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'addvotetotable.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {
          },
          success: function() {
          }
        });

      }
</script>
```

Then in the ajax call which is working properly I declare this for the success:

```
success: function(data) {

            performAjaxSubmission();
},
```

addvotetotable.php looks like:

<

```
?php
// If user submitted vote give the user points and increment points counter

require_once("models/config.php");

//Check to see if there is a logged in user
    if(isUserLoggedIn()) { 
    $username_loggedin = $loggedInUser->display_username;
    }

    if (strlen($username_loggedin)) { 
    include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT vote FROM points_settings WHERE id=1")or die (mysql_error());
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            $points_value=$info['vote'];
    }
     include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO points (id,username,action,points) VALUES ('','$username_loggedin','vote','$points_value')")or die (mysql_error

());
        include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE userCake_Users SET points=points + $points_value WHERE Username='$username_loggedin'")or die (mysql_error());
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Uh, that looks mighty recursive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a value that you want to store in your database in the "data" of the ajax-request. Than you can use this in your php-code using $_POST["something"], check if it's valid... and return f.e. html or json which you than handle in the success-function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function onSubmitVote() 
 {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'addvotetotable.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: "theVoteValue=" + <read_your_vote_value_here>,
          success: function(result) {
          >>>return something in your addvotetotable.php which indicate success and show a message whether the vote was successful or not.<<<
          }
        });

        return false; // prevent submit if it is a submit-type button.

}
</script>
```

What this does is post data of the vote (it's value) to the php-file. There you can read it with `$_POST["theVoteValue"]` and put it in the database. You check if the value is valid and may insert, else you return an error-message or something so that in javascript you can notify the user of it's failure.

Comment: All I really need to do is run addvotetotable.php once the ajax of the voting is complete. Is there some other way to call the php file in the success function?

Comment: You typically call a php using an ajax-request, so I'm not sure why you are performing a request to the php-file and only on succes you want to do something. I think you just want to do a request with the data you want to store and then on success show something. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm using a voting script that uses ajax to register the vote without reloading the page. I noticed that the ajax function they used has a success function. Inside there I want to call my php file to register the vote in my mysql db.

Comment: I think you do not understand how ajax works. I've updated my answer to make it a little more specific, hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: The function you gave me looks perfect, but how do I call it when the voting ajax function is successful?

success: function() {
onSubmitVote();
}

I tried the above and it doesn't work??

Comment: You still don't understand ^^.You don't have to call that function on success. Success means the ajax request was successful, nothing more. If you do call that function in success you will end up in an infinite loop where you keep on calling the vote... You have a button to submit your vote right? When clicking on that button you will have to call this function...